# Angular2 importing module from NPM (Googleapis)

Tags: javascript, google-api, npm, angular

I am building an Angular2 app that is using Webpack for my build process. I would like to create a Google oauth login function in my app. And so I have installed the googleapi package from npm. But I'm running into some trouble importing this package into my app.

I'm trying `import * from 'googleapi';` but this crashes the app with message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

This is my System.config:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    rxjs: 'node_modules/rxjs',
    googleapis: 'node_modules/googleapis'
  },
  meta: {
    googleapis: { format: 'commonjs' }
  },
  packages: {
    app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    rxjs: {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
System.import('app/contacts-app').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

How do I include this package in my app?

Comment: Did you try setting a package `googleapis` instead of meta? Are you including apis file as script in html (you shouldn't)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this library can be used within the browser since it relies on the `google-auth-library` library that uses the `request` one. The latter can only be used within Node applications...

There is a port of the `request` library for the browser: https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-request.

Regarding your error, perhaps you forgot to include SystemJS in your HTML file:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>  <----
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now an `ng-gapi` npm wrapper for googleapis functionality for Angular.  This may support your requirements:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-gapi